# Can't load a vector into fabricJS

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Having trouble loading the svg / vector defined here into Fabric. Here's what it looks like when I load it into the Kitchen Sink demo: [image]

Here's a JS Fiddle that shows the vector being displayed in the browser natively: https://jsfiddle.net/fhgj39rs/1/

This is just raw code `svg` code

Would love some help to figure out if Fabric can render this image (and others like it).

Comment: it looks like attributy display with value none on the group is not respecred.  I'm gonna watch this error for a fix.

Comment: Great thanks @AndreaBogazzi

Comment: found bug, submitted fix. wait for merge. if you want to fix by yourself look here: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/2771

Comment: Great thanks @AndreaBogazzi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like there was a bug in the library itself.

This svg has a shape that then is covered by two rects that have `display="none"` ( i presume some leftover from a template in design process ).

The fabric.js library was parsing the svg correctly but the was setting back the rect's display property from not visibile to visible.

The bug has been found thanks to this question and fixed.
There is no other way to answer this question other than that.

I will propose a close.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AndreaBogazzi.

Comment: I just found another icon that is running into a similar problem. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aLr5nf5e/. Here is how it looks in the KitchenSink: https://i.imgur.com/l95m7ui.png Should I open a new question here, or maybe a GitHub issue? What would you prefer?

Comment: i think is same issue. did you try the proposed fix?

Comment: I did. Looks like it's related but the fix doesn't solve the issue for this icon.

Comment: i'll open a pr as soon as i found out the bug.

Comment: Anyway delete the rect element to have a nice icon working.

Comment: Unfortunately the code comes from a 3rd party and I won't know which ones to delete. Is this a related issue with a rectangle overlapping that icon that can be fixed programatically?